# mysql query for selecting data in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with 10 columns and I want to check input value in `where` clause of the MySQL query.

I want to do something like this. But, when I use this query I am getting an error.

for example :

```
SELECT * FROM user_data 
where poll_title='$poll_title' 
and '$voter' IN (user_vote_1,user_vote_2,user_vote_3...user_vote_10) 
order by idpoll ASC
```

user_vote_1 to 10 (value is null'ed in the database) and I want to retrieve only that rows from a column which have `$voter` value.

Comment: What is the error ? and please specify some more relevant code and Table schema

Comment: Do you have any error message ? Did you verify the variables values ($voter, $poll_title, ...) ?

Comment: this is the error i am getting : 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'' IN(user_vote_1,user_vote_2) ORDER BY poll_id ASC LIMIT 0 , 100 at line 1`

Comment: @Armage yes i have verify it `$voter = test` and `$poll_title = test poll` both are verified and echo out and the out put is correct for both variables.

Comment: now i convert `$voter` variable `to_string` and my condition is failing now.after changing into string query work but condition fail's as it should not be failed.

Comment: @hassan, you should add the error message in the original question, it may help other readers :) Anyway, I'm surprised by the double (simple)quotes around test in the error msg. The $voter is test, not 'test', is that right ?

Comment: yes it's right i make it right after checking the error!

Comment: on question here at this website.every one do negative marking why this happens.than i am unable to ask any more question here.my account is than banned for more question..what the ...is this......:(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this comparison (Not Sure OfCourse) :-

```
SELECT * FROM user_data 
where poll_title = "$poll_title"
  and (user_vote_1 = "$voter"
  OR user_vote_2 = "$voter" 
  OR user_vote_3 = "$voter" 
  OR user_vote_4 = "$voter"......OR user_vote_10 = "$voter")
order by idpoll ASC
```

Comment: if one value will be true than it will retrieve all the data because of `OR` i need more strong comparison as my column contain thousands of values and will only select that row which have only value of `$voter` is this will work in this case???

Comment: This will return only the rows which has `poll_title` as `$poll_title` and any of the columns `user_vote_1 - 10` has a value `$voter`

Comment: i got this error after changing to your code :
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test'' OR user_vote_3 = 'test'' OR user_vote_4 = 'test'') ORDER BY `poll_id` ASC' at line 1`

Comment: There may be some typo - I updated one of them in the query above

Comment: output of this query is not working correctly.it show me full row of data not only single value from the row.it retrieve full row when condition is meet from condition i mean (when one value is in the column it retrieve all the value) i need only that single value not full row.if i echo other columns it should not be able to retrieve data from that columns when there is no match.

Comment: select the column name you want instead of selecting the row by '*' -- change `SELECT *` to `SELECT <column name you want>`

Comment: that will also not help.because i have to select 10 columns for which i am doing this query and it will again insert data from the rest of the 9 when single condition is true.

Comment: what about join's.can i use joins in this query if yes than how?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you want to do - return only the column with the value - then would coalesce do the job? This assumes that the value in user_vote_n will either match the value you're looking for or be null, since coalesce returns the first non-null argument.

(untested)

> select coalesce(user_vote_1, user_vote_2, user_vote_3, ) as UserVote from user_data
>   where coalesce(user_vote_1, user_vote_2, user_vote_3, ) = '$voter';

That aside, this looks like a structure that could do with normalising - a single 'user_vote' column and a single 'user_vote_number' column.

Comment: thank you for reply.
but what is want is that.i want to select all 10 columns from the database and compare that with my variable value and retrieve only row which match the variable data.

Comment: this query doesn't help me out!